# More parameters on the search function

Tags: javascript, react-native, filter, parameters, searchbar

How ca I add more parameters on my search functionality? I tried a lot of methods but the problem is with the filter.

```js
  const searchFilterFunction = (text, filter = 'title') => {
    if (text) {
      const newData = masterDataSource.filter(function (item) {
        const itemDataTitle = item
          ? item[filter].toUpperCase()
          : ''.toUpperCase();
        const textData = text.toUpperCase();
        return itemDataTitle.indexOf(textData) > -1;
      });
      setFilteredDataSource(newData);
      setSearch(text);
    } else {
      setFilteredDataSource(masterDataSource);
      setSearch(text);
    }
  };
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I need to search my items by more parameters in the same time. If the title didn t appear, to appear the author for example.

Comment: So either you need to use an array of filters or your need to have multiple parameters and you have to reference them in the filter function.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
const searchFilterFunction = (param1, param2, param3 = 'param3', param4 = 'param4') => {
    // logic
};
        
searchFilterFunction('param1', 'param2');
searchFilterFunction('param1', 'param2', 'param3overwrite', 'param4overwrite');
```